# Filtering out columns with Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MiJ9.png)I want to filter a pandas data-frame to only keep columns that contain a certain wildcard and then keep the two columns directly to right of this.

The Dataframe is tracking pupil grades, overall total and feedback. I only want to keep the data that corresponds to Homework and not other assessments. So in the example below I would want to keep First Name, Last Name, any homework column and the corresponding points and feedback column which are always exported to the right of this.

First Name,Last Name,Understanding Business Homework,Points,Feedback,Past Paper Homework,Points,Feedback, Groupings/Structures Questions,Points, Feedback

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np 


    all_data = all_data.filter(like=('Homework') and ('First Name') and 
    ('Second Name') and ('Points'),axis=1)

    print(all_data.head())
```

export_csv = all_data.to_csv (r'C:\Users\Sandy\Python\Automate_the_Boring_Stuff\new.csv', index = None, header=True)

Comment: Please provide a sample of the dataset you are working with

Comment: The format is that the CSV starts with First Name, Surname, Then it has the Assessment, Points, Feedback. I want to keep only the Assessments that contain the text "Homework" then the two columns directly to their right. I cant reference them as the column name is duplicated after any assessment.